# Add a label custom field in Salesforce Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to put a checkbox in a salesforce page but the problem is that the required message is more than 40 characters so it doesn't fit in the checkbox label (40 character max)

I tried adding two custom fields on top of the checkbox but the problem that these fields even though if they are read only the user can edit there content(text(255)) or not be able to see them(formula(text)) in edit mode.

Is there any way I can do that without creating a custom page and appending it in the page?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an ideal solution but you could create a new section on your page layout which will allow more text than a label to be displayed. Then only put your confirmation check box field in that section.

That will affectively give you the long label description you are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a very simple Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  I confirm that the new account is open
</apex:page>
```

Set the controller to your object; I use "Account" here.

You then insert the Visualforce page directly into the page layout, just like you would a field.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need visualforce or S-Controls (now deprecated)

An alternate is to make a text box and prepopulate it with the info, but I think that too would need those technologies

If you come up with a solution to this- let me know.